# What happens if the result of match was found wrong after the match day?

Tags: rules, cricket, history

Consider a situation where **Team A** and **Team B** are playing a cricket match,

Team A scored some odd runs (lets assume 250 runs).

Team B is chasing the score, while chasing they require 2 runs from a ball. Bowler bowls the ball Umpire somehow declare it as a NO ball and batsman is able to take only single run from that ball in this case the Team B wins the match because of that NO ball.

Now my question is after a day of the match Team A checks the replays and finds it was not a NO ball or it was not appropriate to say that ball was not legal to be bowled and if that is considered the result should have been tie instead of Team B winning the match, will the result can be changed on the appeal from Team A?

Does they have any right to ask for or report for the same?

If yes then is there any team who have done like this in Cricket History?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. The result stands. [Law 21.10](https://www.lords.org/laws-and-spirit/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-21-the-result,47,AR.html) (Result not to be changed) is very clear:

> Once the umpires have agreed with the scorers the correctness of the scores at the conclusion of the match - see Laws 3.15 (Correctness of scores) and 4.2 (Correctness of scores) - the result cannot thereafter be changed.

In a controversial Test match at The Oval in 2006, the umpires held that Pakistan had [forfeited the match](http://www.espncricinfo.com/engvpak/content/story/257010.html) due to refusing to take the field, and that England had therefore won. This result was then [controversially overturned](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci-icc/content/story/359329.html) by the ICC, who declared that the result should be considered a draw. However, the ICC later [changed the result back to the original decision, a forfeit](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci-icc/content/story/388625.html), after the MCC - the custodians of the Laws - declared that this would set a "dangerous precedent," and that the ICC had no power to change the result. All this underlined the fact that the **umpires' decision must stand**.

Answer (score 4):

As per [Law 3 (The umpires)](http://www.lords.org/laws-and-spirit/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-3-the-umpires,29,AR.html)

> #### 7. Fair and unfair play
>
> The umpires shall be the **sole** judges of fair and unfair play.

So umpire's decision is considered as the last decision. No matter whether it found wrong on the next day. So in the given scenario Team-B remains winner.

Comment: True, but I don't think this query relates to fair and unfair play (which covers matters such as intimidatory bowling, stealing runs, etc.); section 15 of Law 3 may be more relevant (Correctness of scores).